# IntelliJ IDEA - Evaluating expression without consuming iterable

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

Let's assume we have a break point at the start of the while loop,

```
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    // do something with line
}
```

and that the InputStream of the Bufferedreader `reader` has `["there is only one line"]`

In IntelliJ IDEA, evaluating (Ctrl + U) `reader.readLine()` will effectively consume `"there is only one line"` and when I resume from the breakpoint, the while loop condition will fail since there are no more lines in the BufferedReader.

Is there any way to evaluate `reader.readLine()` without consuming the actual line?

Comment: Why not stepping over this line? Then either you are inside the loop and `line != null` or you are just after the loop and `line == null`.

Comment: I vaguely remember that an equivalent functionality inside Eclipse was not consuming the line, which triggered the question on IDEA. 

It was super convenient to see if the line is not null beforehand, and at the same time, know what value was inside before proceeding into the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Evaluating an expression means executing it and seeing the result, so effectively `reader.readline()` will always consume a line.

However, you may want to try `ready()` method, which will return `true`, if a read operation can be performed.

**Note.** In case the reader is about to reach EOF, `ready()` will return `true`, since a read operation can be performed, but will return `null` instantly.

[Java Orace Docs: ready()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#ready())

Answer (score 0):

I would be surprised if in Eclipse there was a functionallity to read the line without consuming the stream/reader.

A possible solution which would allow you to have a breakpoint at line `while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {` and inspecting the value of `line` before entering the loop could be to add a conditional breakpoint (in IntelliJ `CTRL-F8` followed by `CTRL-SHIFT-F8` at that line or make a right click on the breakpoint icon).

[image: conditional breakpoint]

That way the execution will stop as soon `line` would be not null.